# Determining solvability of a nonlinear system

Tags: multivariable-calculus, implicit-function-theorem

> We define the coordinates $u,v,w$ in terms of $x,y,z$:
> \begin{align*}
> u & = x + xyz \\
> v & = y + xy \\
> w & = 2x + z + 3z^2. 
> \end{align*}
> Determine whether this system can be solved for $x,y,z$ in terms of $u,v,w$ near the point $(0,0,0)$.

I don't even know where to start since the system is nonlinear. The first thing I would try to do is rearrange and substitute to solve for $x,y,z$, but I run into issues with nonlinearity (i.e., I can't solve for $z$ without taking the positive and negative root) and division by zero (breaking apart $xyz$). I feel as though this system is not solvable, but I cannot rigorously explain why.

Comment: Do you know the [Implicit function theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem)?

Comment: Implicit function theorem.

Comment: I do know the implicit function theorem, but how do I apply it here? Doesn't it require a linear system?

Comment: @AlgebraMaster Considering your question, I would suggest that you read the theorem again in detail.

Comment: Actually what you need is the *inverse* function theorem (which is equivalent to the implicit function theorem, but still).

Comment: @HansLundmark Could you explain how I could use this? I'm familiar with both theorems, but I don't see how to apply it here.

Comment: Solving for $(x,y,z)$ in terms of  $(u,v,w)$ near a particular point is the same thing as finding a local inverse of the mapping $(x,y,z) \mapsto (u,v,w)$ at that point. So the question is whether a local inverse exists. (You're not supposed to find it.)

Comment: @HansLundmark Is the way to do that to construct a matrix of coefficients and try to construct its inverse?

Comment: No, that's not what the theorem says! It's not a linear system, so what would that matrix be? It's the *Jacobian* determinant that's relevant.